# How can I filter the results by date of a query, using a datepicker value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datepicker, prepared-statement

I'm having trouble making this change on my program, I have some clue of what to do, but not a definitive solution. I want my program to be able to retrieve the data of a specific date using jquery datepicker, but I don't know how to pass the datepicker value to a prepared statement, any idea on how to do it.

```
try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM [" + GeneralData.DATABASE + "].[dbo].[VentasDetalle] "
                + "WHERE [Sucursal] = '" + GeneralData.suc + "' "
                + "AND [Date] = " + /*my doubt*/
        System.out.println(query);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        int rowcount = 0;

        if (rs.last()) {
            rowcount = rs.getRow();
            rs.beforeFirst();
        }

        ids = new String[rowcount];
        prices = new double[rowcount];

        for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
            if (rs.getString("Type").replaceAll("\\s+", "").equals("PROD")) {
                ids[i] = rs.getString("ProductCode").replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                price[i] = rs.getDouble("price");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question can't be both Java and Javascript. Pick one.

Comment: Are you asking how to inject parameters into prepared statements? If so, take a look at the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html which explains how to use '?' as a placeholder for arguments sent at execution. Or is your question specifically about dates?

Comment: your question is about how to pass a vlue from the client side to his server => ajax

Comment: @MisterJojo after doing some research I think you're right, at firts I though I needed a prepared statement to pass the value of my datepicker but since it's a javascript value it only exist on the client side how do i pass it to the server side?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest  or 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch about this